# Is there such a thing as a Conflation Fallacy? Or something like it?

Tags: fallacies

I commonly find this phenomenon when debating, where my statement is conflated with another similar statement or idea.

For example, if Person A. said "X is the highest grossing Horror movie of all time." And Person B. responded "that's not true, the highest grossing movie of all time is Z."

In this case, Person A. was referencing a particular genre, Horror, while Person B. took this statement to mean ALL movies of every genre and conflated them.
Now this could be an accident but I'm looking more for intentional misrepresentations of claims through conflation. I'm looking to see if there is a specific name for this misrepresentation. I know it sounds very similar to a Strawman Argument but it's a very specific kind of misrepresentation through conflation. If anyone could help me identify this type of fallacy that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Irrelevant conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrelevant_conclusion) or ignoratio elenchi.  Also known as "missing the point."

By discussing something other than the assertion, the fallacy simply does not argue against it.